# how to insert foreign key value not id through form in php

Tags: php, sql

my one table (user) contains attributes
user_id|user_name|address|phone_no|designation_id |
where designation_id is a foreign key and 
my 2nd table (designation) contains attributes
designation_id|designation_name| 
i want to insert new entries through form and want to enter foreign key(designation_id) value not id so that this value stores in designation table.My code for insert new data is this but it only takes designation_id not value.

```
if(isset($_POST['user_name']))
  {    
    $user_name=$_POST['user_name'];
    $address=$_POST['address'];
    $phone_no=$_POST['phone_no'];
    $designation_id=$_POST['designation_id'];
       if(mysql_query("insert into user(user_id,user_name,address,phone_no,designation_id) values ('','$user_name','$address','$phone_no','$designation_id')"))
            echo "successful insertion!";
       else
            echo"please try again";
  }
     $res=mysql_query("select * from user");
```

what should i do so that my insert foreign key value not id,it save in designation table.

Comment: Your question is not totally clear, please use interpunction. Do you want to save your `designation_id` in your `designation` table instead of your `user` table? Or in both?

Comment: btw when u put a var inside a single quotes it becomes a string not avar ,u can simply git rid of the quotes and it will work.

Comment: Please explain your request, what do you mean by `want to enter foreign key(designation_id) value not id` ,also on a side note, you need to start using mysqli (improved extensions) or PDO_MySQL extensions , since the mysql_query is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future.

Comment: my designation table contains two attributes (designation_id,designation_name)

Comment: i just want to ask that my user table contains the foreign key so if i make new entry,i have to give the foreign key id i-e(designation_id),i just want to know that can i enter designation_name rather than designation_id in user table which also save in user table as well as designation table,are you clear what im asking about.